# Recibo un "IOException" al asignar "Console.Title"

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el error que pongo captura mas abajo, en sintesis el error esta en que ocurrio una excepcion con el archivo mscorlib.dll y ninguna informacion adicional.

**debo decir**
que tengo otro proyecto de la universidad y me lo corre de lo mas normal, recreando el mismo codigo o solo el Console.Title me da error. ¿A que se deberia?

[image: Error VS 2015]

Comment: @sstan: Me parece que además de corregir las etiquetas se debe corregir el título. No lo hago yo mismo pues no estoy familiarizado con Visual Studio 2015 ni con las etiquetas actuales.

Comment: @Rubén: tienes razón. No quise tomar el tiempo de pensar :). Voy a examinar la pregunta más detenidamente para darle un título más apropiado. Tal vez hasta le deje una respuesta...

Answer (score 1):

El que recibas un `IOException` al tratar de manipular el objeto `Console` usualmente indica de que tu programa simplemente no tiene una consola.  Y la razón más probable por la que sucede esto es porque tu proyecto no es de tipo *Console Application*.

Para verificar esto, abre las propiedades de tu proyecto, y verifica el valor seleccionado para *Output Type*. Si el valor no es *Console Application* (tal vez lo tienes a *Windows Application* o algo por el estilo), cámbialo para que sí lo sea. Esto debería corregir tu error.

Comment: Gracias, no sé a qué se debió pero quizás es porque en el instituto el VS está configurado de manera que trabaje correctamente.                          Ya lo configure de la manera que me indicas y funciono, y si, tratare de ser más específico en las siguientes preguntas que pueda hacer, *gracias*